# Firefox is not displaying tooltip in Edit mode  of  Gridview template

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, gridview

as i am editing a record, as its working perfectly in internet explorer, i set the tooltip for edit by using EditText property in the edit template, same also for the update text. right now it is rendering as expected in IE, but it is not displaying tooltip in firefox,
functionality wise its working fine.

```
      <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" EditText="Click here to edit section" EditImageUrl="../images/edit.gif" HeaderText="Actions"

    UpdateText="click here to update section" UpdateImageUrl="../images/pageok.gif" CancelText="Cancel" 

CancelImageUrl="../images/pagecancel.gif" ShowEditButton="true" 
                                                            ControlStyle-CssClass="LinkNormal" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stackoverflow reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357124/tooltip-not-displaying-in-ie-8-chrome-ff-for-gridview-command-field-update-ca)

You can also use **Item Template** and **Edit Item Template** for this purpose. This is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it wouldn't work in FireFox. You could try programatically modifying the ToolTip property of either the cell or one of the CommandField's controls during the RowDataBound event:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[column_index].ToolTip = "Click here to edit section"; // for cell
        ((ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[column_index].Controls[control_index]).ToolTip = "Click here to edit section"; // for ImageButton
    }
}
```

Example assumes you'd cast to an ImageButton.

Comment: brissles as i have only one cell, whcih is in edit mode, with multpile buttons inside it, how can we access the cell.. as of now three buttons are in one cell.

Comment: You could use the above method and index one of the three buttons using the control_index, probably indexes 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

[ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tooltip.aspx) property is rendered as HTML's [title](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp) property. Check your markup and validate that property is present there. I've tried to set tooltip on my test page and firefox shows it correctly